# Walmart IO API: not subscribed to the service name

Tags: walmart-api

I'm fooling around with the Walmart IO api.  When I make my service call, I run into the following error:

```
403 Forbidden
{"details":{"Description":"The consumer id 42XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXX
 is not subscribed to the service name - iro-item-read-service-nsf - 1.0.0 - prod"}}
```

Does anyone know how to "subscribe" to a service?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Comment: @ЕгорТрегубенко No, I think the Wal-Mart API is dead. From the website: "We are currently in closed Beta and are no longer accepting new registrations"

Comment: this is not the case, they have a new API v2 v3 wallmart.io